# Best way to refresh a list with events in WebView

Tags: html, ios, xcode, webview, uiwebview

I made an iOS app in Swift.

There's also a `UIWebView` in it. This WebView loads a website of my server that contains a list with events. This list/website should reload once a day to keep it up to date.

What is the best way to do it?

Maybe with this meta tag in HTML?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="86400">
```

But, I think this will only count down if the app is open and actually in use. I think this will not work if the app is only open in the background, right?

If so, what's the best an common way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this working solution now:
import UIKit

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var homewebview: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(21600, target: self, selector: #selector(UIMenuController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        self.homewebview.delegate = self
    }
    func update() {
        homewebview.reload()
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().diskCapacity = 0
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().memoryCapacity = 0
    }
}
```